Create exes for multiple python scripts which share common dependencies folder
I have spec file which has analysis as follows:
def create_analysis_exe(script_name):
analysis = Analysis(
    [script_name],
    pathex=[current_path],  # Adjust to your script path
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    noarchive=False
)

pyz = PYZ(analysis.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    analysis.scripts,
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name=script_name.split(".")[0],  # Name executable after the script
    debug=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None      
)
return analysis, exe

analyses = []
exes = []

for script in script_names:
    analysis, exe = create_analysis_exe(script)
    analyses.append(analysis)
    exes.append(exe)

# Combine binaries and datas from all analyses to avoid duplication
all_binaries = []
all_zipfiles = []
all_datas = []

for analysis in analyses:
    all_binaries += analysis.binaries
    all_zipfiles += analysis.zipfiles
    all_datas += analysis.datas

and I am using collect as follows:
coll = COLLECT(
    *exes,  # Add all EXEs
    all_binaries,
    all_zipfiles,
    all_datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    name='_global'  # Adjust output name as needed
)

but somehow it's overwriting some dependencies information i think, which is why the exe's don't work as they should.
If i create exes with separate spec file, i get individual exe and it's dependencies folder. This works without any issues. I am looking for a way to have a single dependencies folder.
Can someone please suggest a way to achieve this or let me know if it is not doable at all?
